# html2pdf: <page></page> generates one blank page

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

I'm using Html2Pdf for converting some HTML files to PDFs. I'm also required to add page breaks for dividing the parts of my documents. For that I use `<page></page>` tags.

I have the following HTML snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    ...
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <page> page 1 </page>
  <page> page 2 </page>
</body>

</html>
```

When run the following procedures, I get a PDF with 3 pages, first one being completely blank:

```
$H2P = new Html2Pdf();
$H2P->writeHTML( $html );
return $H2P->output(__DIR__ .'/statistics.pdf', 'F');
```

How can I solve this issue? I'm using the latest version installed via composer.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I have a blank page between each page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding below snippet in style worked for me.

> body {   margin-top: 0; }

Basically, if you have some margin defined, then you are not at the top of your page when it encounters a named page. So it inserts the named page skipping the existing one.